# Use Twilio to make a call and play a message

Tags: twilio

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to use a single REST request to have Twilio call out to a phone number, and play out a voice message.  The content of the voice message will be different each time, so that message would need to be passed as a parameter.

In looking at the Twilio API "Making Calls" doc, I see this curl sample:

```
$ curl -XPOST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Calls.json \
--data-urlencode "Url=http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml" \
--data-urlencode "To=+14155551212" \
--data-urlencode "From=+14158675309" \
-u 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:your_auth_token'
```

This specifies a URL for an XML configuration.  For dynamic text, is the expectation that I should publish an xml file to a URL before making the REST call, and then provide that URL in the call?   Is there a way to provide the XML as POST data to the end point, rather than using a URL?

Thanks in advance.

gmc

Comment: when u make call using the rest api. You pass a url and that hits when the receiver answer the call.You can pass that message in the url and u can set the twiml on that url to say the message.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can't include the XML as POST data I'm afraid. However, we do offer [TwiML Bins](https://www.twilio.com/console/dev-tools/twiml-bins) which you can use to host your XML without getting a server of your own. Recently we added support for [templating in TwiML Bins](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/02/building-more-powerful-voice-applications-with-enhanced-twiml-bins-templates.html). This means that you can pass URL parameters to a TwiML Bin URL and use those parameters in your response.

So, if you are intending to use speech to text to read out a message with [`<Say>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say) then you could write the following TwiML as a TwiML Bin:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Say>{{ Message }}</Say>
</Response>
```

You'll get a URL that looks like: `https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/EHsomerandomcharacters`

You can then use that URL in your call creation, with a URL parameter of `Message` to read a different message each time.

```
$ curl -XPOST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Calls.json \
--data-urlencode "Url=https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/EHsomerandomcharacters?Message=Hello+from+your+TwiML+Bin!" \
--data-urlencode "To=+14155551212" \
--data-urlencode "From=+14158675309" \
-u 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:your_auth_token'
```

Let me know if that helps at all.